# Create Xcode project from .cpp files

Tags: c++, xcode, command-line-tool

I have many C++ projects/files I would like to create into a`Command Line Tool` file type `.xcodeproj` for debugging purposes. The only way I can think of doing this successfully is to create a new `Command Line Tool` Xcode project > `Type: C++` then add the C++ project directory or files. Is there anyway to do this without creating a new project and manually adding the file(s) to it?

Note: Xcode opens the individual .cpp files by default but they're not associated as a `Command Line Tool` or have an `.xcodeproj` file type.

Comment: no. unless you already using cmake or other build tool that can generate xcode project file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking for doing the same I found this link, I hope to be useful

http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/05/xcode-and-the-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/

the link show you how to configure Xcode to work in an c++ project, is a little tricky but works.

> **Xcode and the Simple C++ Project Structure**
>
> In a previous post, I talked about a A Simple C++ Project Structure that I am using
>   to create a bunch of high-speed daemons for work.
>
> It’s been fun using TextMate 2 and a Terminal to make and run the
>   project, but now that I am getting to the meat of the coding, I’d
>   prefer to use an IDE to help me navigate and debug the code.
>
> Here’s how to set up Xcode 4 on the Mac to compile using our Makefile
>   and run/debug the application.
>
> Note that since these projects already exist, there is a minor
>   shenanigan involved in setup.
>
> **Step 1: Create an External Build System Project**
>
> Start Xcode and choose File / New Project.
>
> Click on Other then choose External Build System.
>
> Click Next.
>
> Input your project name, I use the existing project’s name so that the
>   Xcode project file matches.
>
> Then click Next.
>
> Now you will save this project at the root of the Simple C++ project
>   folder. Just select the project root and hit Create.
>
> **Step 2: Move the Project File**
>
> The problem is this. If you has chosen the root of your Projects
>   folder where the Simple C++ project resides, Xcode would have replace
>   the simple project folder with a blank folder and its *.xcodeproj
>   file. That’s not what we want.
>
> So instead, we chose the root of the project itself.
>
> But Xcode has created a subfolder named after your project and placed
>   the *.xcodeproj file in that. That’s not what we want either. So lets
>   fix it up.
>
> Quit XCode.
>
> Drag the *.xcodeproj from the subfolder and drop it on the project
>   root. Now delete the subfolder.
>
> Double-click the moved *.xcodeproj to open the project again in Xcode.
>
> **Step 3: Add the sources**
>
> At the bottom left of the Xcode window, click the + icon. Then choose
>   Add files to “Your Project Name”.
>
> Select everything except the build folder and choose Add.
>
> **Step 4: Test the Build**
>
> Click on the project at the top to see the Project and Targets panel.
>   You should see an External Build Tool Configuration already setup to
>   use the Makefile we had before.
>
> To build, press ⌘B.
>
> **Step 5: Run It**
>
> We still need to do one more thing and that is to tell Xcode which
>   executable to run.
>
> Under the Product menu, choose Scheme then Edit Scheme.. or press ⌘<.
>
> Click on Run in the left pane. The click on the drop-down next to
>   Executable and choose Other…. Find the executable in the bin folder
>   and click on it.
>
> If you prefer, you can change the debugger to GDB as well.
>
> To pass arguments to the default run, click the arguments tab and add
>   them there.
>
> Click OK to save.
>
> Press ⌘R to run, and Xcode will bring up a console window to display
>   the program’s output.